# kafka-configs not applying dynamically

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a `server.properties` file that contains the following:

```
listener.name.internal.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="broker" password="admin_password" \
user_admin="test123";

listener.name.external_sasl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="broker" password="admin_password" \
user_admin="test123";
```

If I try and produce messages using the username `user_admin` and the password `test123` I am able to.

However, If I want to update the password for `user_admin` I have found that the changes do not apply until a restart. I am applying the changes using the following:

```
kafka-configs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --broker 1 --alter --add-config-file /etc/kafka/users.conf
```

`/etc/kafka/users.conf` contains the following:

```
listener.name.internal.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="broker" password="admin_password" \
user_admin="test1234";

listener.name.external_sasl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="broker" password="admin_password" \
user_admin="test1234";
```

Now if I try and produce messages using the password `test1234` I am told my username/password is incorrect. If I restart my Broker, then I can produce messages using `test1234`. However, my understanding was that using the `kafka-configs` command should update the config without a restart.

I have checked ZooKeeper and can confirm that the config does appear in ZooKeeper after running `kafka-configs`

Is anyone able to advise as to where I am going wrong here?

Comment: What version of Kafka are you using? Not all configs are dynamic at all versions. Also, there are other options that don't require modifying a file, such as LDAP authorization or Apache Ranger

Comment: 6.1.5-1 - Confluent Kafka